# Income Statement Subtotals In Tableau Worksheet

Tags: tableau-desktop

[Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cvizSvrDBMZtDjxxvjLMIJAoHjNdB6Oz/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114912691694990958283&rtpof=true&sd=true)
First, I am trying to create your basic multi-level income statement.

Gross Sales
Discounts
Net Sales
COGS
Gross Profit

and so on. I have tried turning on subtotals for all columns. I have searched for an answer for days now, but the one example on the Tableau forum has SUM(Amount) only. It has various different groups; covering the income statement categories. This example has a grouping of groups. I can mimic this, but it gets me no closer to, for example, calculating gross profit (net sales minus cost of sales). For presentation purposes, all of the values need to be positive, except of course if there is negative gross profit; e.g., a loss. Therefore, for some subtotals I am subtracting one subtotal from another. I am relatively new to Tableau and I am at a dead end since I don't know where to turn. My data sheet is simply an Excel workbook with transaction date, account, product, product category, and amount.

[image: Sample output]

Comment: could you please provide some sample input data and some output in order to add a little more context?

Comment: @FabioFantoni I added a hyperlink to Google with sample data and a screenshot of the output I am trying to achieve.